# How should I structure my ruby gem command line service?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, command-line-interface, network-service

I'm writing a ruby gem that users can install and use the command line ruby tool to interact with the service. You can start and stop the service (it will spawn off a child process).

I've done a lot of research into the best things to use to write a network service, such as ØMQ/EventMachine and I get how to create a Ruby gem that will install a binary you can use in the command line, but I'm struggling to set out a good code structure.

My command line utility will take various arguments (I'll use [Trollop](http://trollop.rubyforge.org/)) and the it will use various classes to do things, and use various other ruby gems.

I'm not sure where I should put my class files, and how to require them in my binary so the paths are correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Largely, RubyGems will take care of this for you.  You'll need to include your executable in the `files` list, and put it in the `executables` in your gemspec.  It's common to put your executable in `bin` in your directory, e.g.:

```
$ ls
bin/   myapp.gemspec  lib/    Rakefile
$ ls bin
bin/myapp
```

Your gemspec would then look like:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = 'myapp'

  # whatever else is in your gemspec

  s.files = ["bin/myapp","lib/myapp.rb"]  # or whatever other files you want
  s.executables = ["bin/todo"] 
end
```

At this point, when users install your app via RubyGems, `myapp` will be in their path, and `lib` will be in your app's loadpath, so your executable can simply start off with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'myapp'
# whatever other requires
```

The only issue with this is that, during development, you cannot just do `bin/myapp` and have your app run.  Some devs manipulate the load path via `$:` or `$LOAD_PATH`, but this is considered bad form.

If you are using bundler, it's easiest to just run your app locally with `bundle exec`, e.g. `bundle exec bin/myapp`.  You can alternately use the `RUBYLIB` environment variable, e.g. `RUBYLIB=lib bin/myapp`, which will put `lib` in the load path.

Answer (score 4):

You can generate a gem project structure with [Bundler](http://gembundler.com).

Briefly:

**Install Bundler**

```
$ gem install bundler
```

**Use Bundler to generate the gem project**

```
$ bundle gem myapp
$ cd myapp
```

**Add an executable**

```
$ mkdir bin
$ cat > bin/mycommand << EOSCRIPT
  #!/usr/bin/env ruby

  require 'myapp'

  puts "Executing myapp"
  EOSCRIPT
$ chmod +x bin/mycommand
```

**Install your Gem**

```
$ rake install
```

**Run your script**

```
$ mycommand
Executing mycommand
```

**Share your utility on rubygems.org**

```
$ rake release
```

More docs on [the website](http://gembundler.com)

Answer (score 0):

Since all gems are open source by nature, you could always have a look at some of the better ones for examples. Using a gem builder like `jeweler` or `hoe` would also set you up with some of the basic structure organizationally speaking.

Comment: "Source-available" might be a better term. Just because you can see the source code doesn't mean that it's "open source" software in the usual sense.

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look at those! I'm not a ruby developer by day so i'm struggling to get a good footing.

Comment: I meant more "open source" as in I don't know of any that are deliberately obfuscated. This is where "open source" and "free open source" differ. Still, the vast majority of gems are published with some kind of open-source license.